# How to add text to the _content field in a Solr index for a Sitecore implementation?

Tags: indexing, sitecore, solr4, sitecore7.5

This is for a Sitecore 7.5 - Solr 4.7 implementation. I would like to be able to modify the text that is stored in the _content field in Solr.  I believe that somehow that Sitecore aggregates all of the content fields for an item in the _content field in the index. (I think that is correct) At index time I would like to be able to write my own code that could potentially modify the text that is stored in the _content field in Solr.  Is this possible?  Any ideas how I would go about this?

Answer (score 5):

`_content` is a computed field, which means the value is resolved at the point that the item is crawled. You'll see the computed field is defined in your config:

```xml
<field fieldName="_content" returnType="string" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.MediaItemContentExtractor,Sitecore.ContentSearch">
  <mediaIndexing ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration/mediaIndexing"/>
</field>
```

I recommend decompiling the class specified in the `type` attribute to see what it does. Then you can create your own computed field class (or inherit from that one), and replace the type attribute.

Computed fields are really quite simple to work with. They implement `IComputedIndexField` which requires a `ComputeFieldValue` method. The method accepts an argument of type `IIndexable` (in most cases the concrete class is an `Item`) and is called every time an item is crawled.

So in the `ComputeFieldValue` method you could cast the `Iindexable` to an `Item`, then return a concatenated string of all the field values you want to include from that item.

See here for more on computed fields:

http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2013/03/sitecore-7-computed-index-fields.aspx

Comment: Yeah I went down that road.  The odd thing to me is that the class that it references is Sitecore.ContentSearch.ComputedFields.MediaItemContentExtractor.  When I look at the code for that class it seems like it only applies to media items.  It seems to return NULL for every non-media content item.  So from what I can gather _content will be null except for media items.  That seems odd to me.  Maybe I am misunderstanding what the _content field actually is.  I assumed that _content was an aggregation of all fields for all types of content items.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you can add another (separate) `_content` field with your own `IComputedIndexField` implementation. The resulting values from all added fields with the same name are aggragated.

See also: https://kamsar.net/index.php/2014/05/indexing-subcontent/ and https://andrewwburns.com/2015/09/03/appending-to-the-_content-field-in-sitecore-search-7-2-and-7-5/